# Posix thread tutorial

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, posix

I'm looking for a comprehensive pthread tutorial. I considered buying [Programming with posix threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633922) but this book seems is bit dated. Other online tutorials like [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) are very basic. Can someone please suggest a good and complete pthread tutorial.

Comment: That book looks pretty good to me.  The fundamentals of Pthreads won't have changed, so this is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I can confirm that's a pretty awesome book. And most things haven't changed much since it was written.

Comment: Wow the negative reviews of that book seem to be coming from idiots... for example, complaining that the examples of mutexes have the mutex associated with data rather than code.

Comment: Just wondering: why aren't you using a more portable library, like boost::thread?

Comment: I have this book (somewhere). When the only standard (as in POSIX) threading library we had was pthreads I used it constantly (its like the the pthread bible). Nowadays though I use boost

Comment: I agree with Owen - POSIX threads don't change much over time so the resource should be a good starting point. The why and how is more important than the specific API, which is always available from Google.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory has an excellent tutorial at:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: This is what I'm reading right now, but I don't like it. Examples are wrong, In one section author is saying do not do this and in next section he himself is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The LLNL one is good but I also found http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/ which is for C but clearly written and very useful.

Comment: Decent tutorial. I like the writing style and material.

Answer (score 3):

This should helpers:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: Very concise and to the point. This seems to be a good review that one can come back to as a lite reference once he knows the basic concept, not so much a beginner tutorial.