# Timer tick event in C++ , Linux

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

Please help me out friends. I just want to implement a timer event function. Let me describe it properly.

In main function a continuous operation will run (suppose a print in a while(1) loop).

but there should be another function which will be invoked repeatedly after a certain time of interval (suppose 2 sec).  But the operation being executed in main function should not be hampered for that. I think I have to implement threading here.

This is like tick event in visual studio.

I want it in C++ gcc or g++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to track time yourself:

First, a helper function

```
double GetSeconds()
{
    struct timeval Time;
    gettimeofday( &Time, NULL );
    int64_t T = Time.tv_usec + Time.tv_sec * 1000000;
    return static_cast<double>( T ) / 1000000.0;
}
```

And the main piece of code to use it, which is basically a busy-loop:

```
const double EventTime = 2.0; // seconds

double StartTime = GetSeconds();

while (...)
{
   double T = GetSeconds();
   double DeltaTime = T-StartTime;

   if ( DeltaTime > EventTime )
   {
      FireEvent();
      StartTime = T;
   }
}
```

You can run this loop in a separate thread or you can interleave it with your `while (1)` loop. The choice is yours.

In case of threads, you can refer to this tutorial: [Posix thread tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058722/1065190)

Comment: Actually that was my fault, I have given an example of while(1). Actually the scenario is not exactly like that. the main control of the program can go to anywhere. it can go out of that while loop, even can go to any other functions. the control of that program can circulate among any other functions.

But the timer event only will fire repeatedly after 2 sec interval, and it will give me a notification that is is being called for various times on 2 sec interval.

That is what i want.

Comment: I am not familiar to C++ threads. I know C# and Java thread, but don't know c++ threads

Comment: @Ankur: I added a link to my answer